# JSP issues and org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter on Hybris

Tags: java, jsp, upgrade, sap-commerce-cloud

Hi everyone i have a problem with the build.compiler=org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter. I am currently working on an upgrade of SAP Hybris to version 2105. When I run 'ant clean all' I get the following error ''/hybris/bin/platform/resources/ant/util.xml:84: Class not found: org .eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter".

I changed in advanced.properties build.compiler to 'modern' so that it compiles with JDK. What I don't know is if it's the right way.

I have managed to run the project but several of the JSP components do not run for me.

My question is whether it may be because the 'buiild.compiler' should be 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter' or it may be due to some other issue

Comment: Have you tried using SAP Jdk?

Comment: yes but the JSPs are not working yet

Comment: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [An exception occurred processing [/WEB-INF/views/responsive/pages/cart/cartPage.jsp] at line [12]

9: 
10: <spring:htmlEscape defaultHtmlEscape="false" />
11: 
12: <template:page pageTitle="${pageTitle}">
13: 
14:     <cart:cartValidation/>
15:     <cart:cartPickupValidation/>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.util.HtmlSanitizerPolicyProvider